# How to call end point from java directly

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a requirement to call one of the back end service end point directly from java code, is there a way to achieve it.

To summarize, I need to create end point in wso2 esb, get the reference of end point in java and finally invoke end point from java.

Comment: What kind of endpoint are you using. An endpoint may be specified as an address endpoint, WSDL based endpoint, a load balancing endpoint, a fail-over endpoint or a HTTP endpoint.

Comment: It can be simple address end point. My requirement is to call simple address end point from java mediator.

Comment: What do you mean by "directly from java code"? Depending on what kind of transport are your endpoint using you'll need to choose a different strategy. If you can configure the ESB would be easier if you create a REST call over HTTP.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel for your response.  Your question "What do you mean by "directly from java code"?" was I want to get the reference of the EP in java mediator and invoke the that end point from the mediator. I know it's weird by hearing but I got into peculiar requirement to implement this way.

Comment: Are you writing a custom mediator for wso2?